# Ubuntu upstart script error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, upstart

I am getting an error:

```
init: zeus main process (1636) terminated with status 1
```

when i try to run my very simple upstart script which looks like this:

```
#!upstart
description ""
author      ""

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/zeus
    xvfb-run node --harmony www
    emit zeus_running
end script
```

Any ideas on what the actual problem is? I have added a pre-stgart and post-start script section with logs and I have confirmed that it is failing in the main script that i have posted here.

Comment: `emit zeus_running`: what is this `zeus_running` function? Seems pretty clear from the error message that your problem is in there.

Comment: `init-checkconf zeus.conf` gives an error on my system: `ERROR: File zeus.conf: syntax invalid:
init:zeus.conf:2: Expected token`. I had to type something in the description and author fields or remove them to satisfy the check.

Comment: Ok, so you can go ahead and delete then?

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, I deleted the contents between the description and author values just to keep it simple for the posts sake and the "emit zeus_running" is an event that is fired in case later on I wanted to chain the event with another script or something. when i run "init-checkconf zeus.conf" i get: File /etc/init/zeus.conf: syntax ok